# Git Hook Pull with PHP not working on Shared Hosting

Tags: php, git, githooks

I have a script to pull a repository like this

```
<?php 

function execPrint($command) {
    $result = array();
    exec($command, $result);
    foreach ($result as $line) {
        print($line . "\n");
    }
}


print("<pre>" . execPrint("git pull https://username:password@gitlab.com/repo/dummy-hooks.git master") . "</pre>");

?>
```

i've been try on my own VPS it's working well but when I try on shared hosting it's not working ..

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: that surely has to do with your hosting company policy allowing to run ```exec```. Best thing you can do is to contact their technical support.

Comment: In what way it doesn't work? What's the error message?